# Is it possible to set listeners on web3js contracts transfer method?

Tags: web3js, javascript

Im trying to transfer erc20 tokens in web3js

here is the code I am using

```
let minABI = [
// transfer
{
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
        {
            "name": "_to",
            "type": "address"
        },
        {
            "name": "_value",
            "type": "uint256"
        }
    ],
    "name": "transfer",
    "outputs": [
        {
            "name": "success",
            "type": "bool"
        }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "function"
}
];
let contractAddres="put the erc20 contract address here";

let contract = await new web3.eth.Contract(minABI, contractAddr);

contract.methods.transfer("your account", "amount of erc20 tokens you want transfer").send({
        from: "your account"
    });
```

**the problem is how can I notify user after transfer is finished like `sendTransaction` method**

```
// using the event emitter
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe',
    to: '0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe',
    value: '1000000000000000'
})
.on('transactionHash', function(hash){
    ...
})
.on('receipt', function(receipt){
    ...
})
.on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){ ... })
.on('error', console.error); // If a out of gas error, the second parameter is the receipt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `contract.methods.myMethod.send` also supports event emitter, so in your case the code should look like this:

```
contract.methods.transfer("your account", "amount of erc20 tokens you want transfer").send({
    from: "your account"
})
.on('transactionHash', function(txHash) {
    console.log(txHash);
})
.on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt) {
    console.log(confirmationNumber, receipt);
})
.on('receipt', function(receipt) {
    console.log(receipt);
})
.on('error', function(error, receipt) {
    console.log(error, receipt);
});
```